# How are both of these variables the same?

Tags: java, string, long-integer

Why is it that these two integers

```
Long num = new Long(21); 
long num2 = 21;
```

return true when compared (num==num2)

But this string

```
String word1 = "Hello";
String word2 = new String("Hello");
```

return false when compared (word1==word2)?

Comment: I can't improve on Rohit Jain's answer, but I would like to point out one other thing:  You said, "these two integers".  I don't see two integers; I see two _variables_.  One of the variables holds a long value, and the other one holds an object reference.  Variables, values, objects, and object references are all different things, and you can not truly understand Java until you understand how they are different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, you compare a `Long` reference with the `long` primitive type, in which case the `Long` reference undergo automatic [unboxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8), and the comparison is done between two primitive longs, and hence they are equal. This is in accordance with [JLS §5.6.2 - Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

While in second case, you are comparing two different references, both pointing to two different objects, and hence they have different value, and return `false`.

Comment: +1. And a note to the OP: if you had done `Long num2 = 21L` (note the capitalized "Long" and the "21L"), then `num != num2`. In that case, you're comparing two `Long` objects, and those are compared like any other objects: by reference equality.

Comment: I would point out that if you want to compare two strings for equality, you should be using `word1.equals(word2)` instead of `word1 == word2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your former example `num` is cast to a `long` and the comparison succeeds.

In your second case the two different objects have different addresses and are therefore `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the case of numeric equality, the JVM performs autounboxing (ie it turns the `Long` into a `long`) since one argument of `==` is a `long`.

In the second case, `"Hello"` and `new String("Hello")` are two different *objects*. And in the case of objects, `==` is true only if references are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In first case

**num** is downcasted to **long** and compared by value 21, so it returns true.

In second case

**new** operator in java always creates new object, so **word2** points to new object, so **word1==word2** returns false.